# How can i print the square roots of odd numbers in a given list by using lis comprehension only?

Tags: python

The below gives only the odd numbers, but not the square roots.
How can I add additional features like writing the square roots for the odd numbers?

```
my_list=[x for x in range(1,10) if x%2!=0]

print my_list
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you insert the value of `x` into the array, take the square root of it.

```
my_list=[x**.5 for x in range(1,10) if x%2!=0]
```

You can also use the **[`math`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html)** module, and specifically, the [**`math.sqrt`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.sqrt) function.

```
import math
my_list = [math.sqrt(x) for x in range(1,10) if x%2!=0]
```

Comment: Works great on my computer.  Check another part of your code.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: why would this not work?   
 values =  raw_input()


 numbers = [x**2 for x in values.split(',')  if int(x)%2!=0]


 print     ','.join(numbers)

Comment: You have to cast `x` to an int when you do `x**2`.  Change `x**2` to `int(x)**2`.

Comment: typeerror:sequece item 0: expected string, int found 
when i try with int.

Comment: I'm not sure what your code is, but mine is working with `[int(x)**2 for x in values.split(",") if int(x)%2!=0]`

Comment: ok, i was using "  print ','.join(numbers)  "  and it was giving me an error. But, when i used 'print numbers' it worked fine. Do you know why?

Comment: Oh.  The reason that doesn't work is because the `join()` function will only join strings.  You can do `print ",".join([str(i) for i in numbers])`